# Pandas groupby(), but ignore blank "" strings

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get goupby() in pandas to ignore certain strings, say like a "" from a csv import file?  I've got some data I need to group by an ID field and a column that must contain a unique float value.  However, the data may come in with the same ID but the user never entered in a float value.  In this case I still need to groupby() those records.

```
# example dataframe
tempdf = pd.DataFrame({'idField' : ['A1', 'A1', 'B2', "B2"],
                       'floatValue' : [1.0, "", 3.0, 4.0],
                       'Term' : ['this is 1st A', 'This is 2nd A', "This is 1st B", "This is 2nd B"]})
# groupby()
groupbyList = ['idField', 'floatValue']
tempdf = tempdf.groupby(groupbyList).agg(lambda x: ','.join([str(elem) for elem in (list(set(x)))])).replace(np.nan, "").reset_index()
tempdf
```

Desired output table:

| idField | floatValue | Term |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1.0 | 'this is 1st A', 'This is 2nd A' |
| B2 | 3.0 | 'this is 1st B' |
| B2 | 4.0 | 'this is 2nd B' |

Comment: Your question does not clearly specify the wanted behaviour. You are saying you want to ignore empty cells, but what if there was another row with `[A1, '', 2.0, 'some text']`. Which row should the `A1` column with missing `floatValue` be grouped with? The one wit `1.0` or `2.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preprocess the data, replacing empty strings with nan's and then using `ffill` to propagate the last valid value forward to next valid:

```py
tempdf['floatValue'] = tempdf['floatValue'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()

#...
```

Comment: doing a little preprocessing and replacing empty strings with nan's was actually a really good idea, it caused groupby() to create the output I wanted.  But now I'm having computational issues with my groupby() calls.  Where originally they took seconds to run, they are now running a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = (
    tempdf.groupby(["idField", (tempdf["floatValue"] != "").cumsum()])
    .agg({"floatValue": "first", "Term": ", ".join})
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  idField floatValue                          Term
0      A1        1.0  this is 1st A, This is 2nd A
1      B2        3.0                 This is 1st B
2      B2        4.0                 This is 2nd B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate) after forward-filling the floatValue:

```
out = (tempdf
 .assign(floatValue=pd.to_numeric(tempdf['floatValue'], errors='coerce')
                      .ffill())
 .groupby(['idField', 'floatValue'], as_index=False)
 .agg({'Term': ', '.join})
)
```

Output:

```
  idField  floatValue                          Term
0      A1         1.0  this is 1st A, This is 2nd A
1      B2         3.0                 This is 1st B
2      B2         4.0                 This is 2nd B
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(tempdf.assign(
    floatValue = tempdf['floatValue'].mask(tempdf['floatValue'].eq('')))
 .ffill().groupby(['idField', 'floatValue'])['Term'].agg(list).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  idField  floatValue                            Term
0      A1         1.0  [this is 1st A, This is 2nd A]
1      B2         3.0                 [This is 1st B]
2      B2         4.0                 [This is 2nd B]
```